# Can I write a C++ concept that requires a function-template to which some enum value must be supplied as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, enums, c++20, c++-concepts

I'd like to write a C++ concept that describes a type with a function-template that's specialised by an enum value. e.g.,

```cpp
enum class categories { 
  t1, 
  t2 
};

struct notifiable_type {
  template<categories category>
  auto notification() {}
};

auto main() -> int {
  notifiable_type().notification<categories::t1>();
}
```

So far, I've tried:

```cpp
// 1
template<typename notifiable_t, typename notification_t>
concept notifiable = std::is_enum<notification_t>::value && requires(notifiable_t t, const notification_t n) {
  { t.template notification<n>() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

// 2
template<typename notifiable_t, typename notification_t>
concept notifiable = std::is_enum<notification_t>::value && requires(notifiable_t t) {
  { t.template notification<std::declval<notification_t>()>() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

However, neither of these seem to work in the desired way:

1. The first case has the error `Constraint variable 'n' cannot be used in an evaluated context`.
2. The second case compiles without any errors, but `notifiable<notifiable_type, categories>` isn't satisfied.

Can anyone clarify this for me? Is what I'm trying to write possible?

Comment: It cannot work because the call may be well-formed for only some values of the enumeration. The compiler would generally need to verify each value individually. Where should the concept be used that needs to be able to make the call for _all_ values of the enumeration? (Also note that an object of an `enum` type can generally take on values that are not listed as named enumerators. So there aren't only two values to verify. In your example it would be every `int` value.)

Comment: Or another way: Why doesn't the concept take `notification_t n` as non-type template parameter to pass on to the call in the requirement? Then the user can specify the exact value(s) it relies on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close with this one (I went ahead and changed `std::is_enum<E>::value` to `std::is_enum_v<E>`, and also reduced the names of the types since they're quite long and nearly identical to each other which confused me for a bit):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename E>
concept notifiable =
    std::is_enum_v<E>
    && requires(T t, const E n) {
        { t.template notification<n>() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
```

The problem is you can't use `n` like that because it needs to be a constant, and it's not. So the solution is to instead of inventing a *variable* of type `E` to instead invent a *value* of type `E`. And, well, `0` is as good a value as any:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename E>
concept notifiable = std::is_enum_v<E>
    && requires(T t) {
        { t.template notification<E{}>() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
```

Since `E` is an enum, we know `E{}` is valid. No need for `declval`, which likewise has the same problem as your original approach: it's not a constant and it needs to be.

A similar, though much more verbose and generally weirder, solution would be:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename E>
concept notifiable = std::is_enum_v<E>
    && requires(T t, std::integral_constant<E, E{}> n) {
        { t.template notification<n>() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
```

This, now, works because `integral_constant<T, V>` is constexpr-convertible to a `T` with value `V`. That conversion is extremely useful in a lot of contexts, since it allows something approximating passing constants as function parameters in a way that preserves their constant-ness.

But in this case it's pointless, so I'm just presenting it for illustration.

---

Note that this is still limited, we're only checking that specifically `E{0}` works - not that any `E` works (which we can't in general do). That's likely good enough, although you could get false negatives if, say, you have some situation where `T::notification` has extra constraints on its `E`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting explicit integral values to an enum is generally frowned upon, but this might be one situation where it's the least of all evils. And, a zero is just as good of a victim of a cast as any other number.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c6eYTfK1v)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

template<typename notifiable_t, typename notification_t>
concept notifiable = std::is_enum<notification_t>::value &&
    requires(notifiable_t t) {
    { t.template notification<notification_t{0}>() }
    -> std::same_as<void>;
};


enum class categories {
    t1,
    t2
};

struct notifiable_type {
    template<categories category>
    void notification() {}
};

template<notifiable<categories>> struct t {
};

t<notifiable_type> u;   // OK

struct not_notifiable_type {
};

t<not_notifiable_type> v;  // ERROR
```